# Function macro that evaluates to zero and can be used as a statement

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

We have a function macro `#define FOO(arg) foo(arg)` with `int foo(const char* bar);`. When NDEBUG is  defined FOO is defined as `#define FOO(arg) 0`, however this causes many compiler warnings because in many cases FOO's return value is not used. The solution should work with with ANSI C compilers and cause no warnings. I've tried:

`(void)0`: can't be assigend to variable

`static int foo(const char* bar) { return 0; }` : causes unused static function warning in some modules

`static inline int foo(const char* bar) { return 0; }` : only works with C99 compilers

Thanks for your help!

edit1:
It's somewhat like a trace macro and used all over the project. Mostly it's just used as a statement like `FOO("function x called");`, but in a few cases I saw `if (FOO("condition a")) { /* some more debug output */ }`. With NDEBUG defined and optimization enabled nothing should be left of FOO. I didn't come up with this, but I have to clean up this mess :).

edit2: I should add that for gcc release builds these flags are used: -O3 -Wall -ansi

edit3: For now I'm going with `__inline int dummy() { return 0; }`. __inline works with both VisualC and GCC in ansi mode.

Comment: Can you show more examples of how `FOO()` is used in your code?

Comment: Do you always use the return value from, eg, `printf()`?

Comment: If you don't mind calling foo() and just want to be sure the return value used is 0 you can use the comma operator and `#define FOO(arg) (foo(arg), 0)`

Answer (score 4):

I *guess* it's a little bit compiler dependent but this should work:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    #define FOO(arg) foo(arg)
#else
    #define FOO(arg) ((int)0)
#endif
```

It prevents the "expression has no effect" warning, it does nothing and its value when used is still 0.

**EDITED**
It seems it's something not so portable so (now) you have these conditions:

- `(0)` or `((int)0)` work at least on VC 2010.
- `__noop` should work on any version of VC after 2003.

VC6 is not a problem because it doesn't emit the C4555 warning at all. For other compilers you may use:

- `((void)0, 0)` It may work on a lot of compilers (maybe it's the more portable one?).
- `inline int foo(const char* bar) { return 0; }` works with any other C99 compiler (as you wrote you may need to declare it as `static` on gcc).

For any other prehistoric C compiler use the solution pointed by @Jobs: `abs(0)`

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why this works... Note that on GCC, the cast isn't even necessary.

Comment: I still get the warning with -Wall

Comment: @maep Are you using VC? I'm using 2k10 and it doesn't give any warning (as pointed by Job in most compilers even the cast is unnecessary). What kind of warning you get?

Comment: On GCC you get `warning: statement with no effect`. I just noticed I first tested your example wrongly:-)

Comment: @Adriano: I'm working with gcc 4.4 but we're building on all VS compilers starting with 6.0 (ouch, I know), Intel, Sun and some other UNIX flavors.

Comment: would `int err = __noop;` work? concerning your question: Without link-time optimization those calls won't be completely removed. Also, I just noticed that it should be `static inline`, gcc seems to be more lenient than other compilers.

Comment: Yes, it works (that's the way it is used in VC libraries). For other stuffs yes, I guess you have to provide different methods for different compilers...big big #if sequence! :)

Answer (score 3):

What you *could* do to prevent the warning is the following:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    #define FOO(arg) foo(arg)
#else
    #define FOO(arg) abs(0)
#endif
```

I'm not saying this is ideal (you'd have to make sure `stdlib.h` is included everywhere, for example) but it does prevent the warning.

Comment: This could work but as you say it's not ideal. I'd have to check if the compiler will remove this in release builds.

Comment: @maep: Yes I thought of that issue too. However, I *hope* any decent compiler will remove it in release builds. BTW, GCC seems to remove it even at `-O0`.

Comment: Some compilers might warn about calling a pure function and not using the return value...

Comment: gcc likes this, however clang will complain.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something that is dependent on the C version. In the header file:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ > 199900L
inline int foo(const char* bar) { return 0; }
#else
int foo(const char* bar);
#endif
```

in one compilation unit

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ < 199900L
int foo(const char* bar) { return 0; }
#else
int foo(const char* bar);
#endif
```

or use for the oldish C version something like Job's answer, that is a function that is certain to be optimized out but that doesn't produce the warning.